# What is the number 30.5 in the predict.survreg documentation example referring to?

Tags: r, survival, prediction

The documentation of the `survreg.predict` function contains two examples.

The first example is straightforward,

```
pred <- predict(fit, newdata=list(age=1:65), type='quantile', p=c(.1, .5, .9)) 
matlines(1:65, pred, lty=c(2,1,2), col=1)
```

But in the second example the fitted values and confidence bands are divided by a mysterious number `30.5`!

```
ptime <- predict(lfit, newdata=data.frame(ph.ecog=2), type='quantile', p=pct, se=TRUE)
matplot(cbind(ptime$fit, ptime$fit + 2*ptime$se.fit, ptime$fit -2*ptime$se.fit)/30.5, 
        1-pct, xlab="Months", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
```

I need to use this function to make plots similar to the second example, but I don't understand where this could this number come from. Any thoughts?

[Here's the link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.survreg.html) to the documentation.

Comment: Since this turns out to be an `R` coding issue, and not actually a statistical issue, we should migrate this to [SO] for you.

Comment: @gung I'm on the fence about closing/migrating this just because the answer is so prosaic. It does *seem* like the constant could have some statistical importance. (Also this is a terrible "quirk" to have in the docs!)

Comment: I suspect it is a guess at the average number of days in a month.

Answer (score 6):

It appears the original data are survival times in days, and the author of the example preferred to plot the data in months for simplicity.  Because there are approximately 30.5 days in a month (on average), they divided to get a rough number of months.  Here are the two plots:

```
matplot(cbind(ptime$fit, ptime$fit + 2*ptime$se.fit, ptime$fit - 2*ptime$se.fit)/30.5, 
        1-pct, main="With scaling by 30.5", 
        xlab="Months", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
```

[image]

```
matplot(cbind(ptime$fit, ptime$fit + 2*ptime$se.fit, ptime$fit - 2*ptime$se.fit), 
        1-pct, main="Without scaling by 30.5", 
        xlab="Months (actually days)", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
```

[image]